# Laravel belongsToMany Intermediary Table

Tags: laravel

I have 3 tables that look like this:

**Market**

- id
- name

**Market_to_City**

- market_id
- city_id

**City**

- id
- name

and a model that looks like:

```
class Market extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'Market';

    public function citys() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('City', 'Market_to_City', 'market_id', 'city_id');
    }
}
```

Each market has many cities mapped through the Market_to_City table. The citys method should return a collection of cities that are related to a market. This however returns an empty collection every time, am I using the correct model relationship?

Comment: what is the question? How to write the select query? You don't need a pivot table for that.

Comment: Thanks, updated the post to actually ask a question!

Comment: Are you positive you have matching data in your tables?  For example if you have a market with id of 1, you can see in your Market_to_City table rows with a markey_id of 1 and those rows each have value cities.

Comment: @user3158900 yup. There are entries in the Market_to_City table that correctly contain a market_id and city_id (the primary key of those respective models).

Comment: It would seem as though you are setting up the relationships correctly.  How exactly are you implementing them?

Comment: `$market = GTM_Market::find(205);
echo $market->cities;` Is my implementation.

Comment: I agree with the others. Everything looks correct in your setup. Something else is going on.

Comment: I'm not sure what happens when you just try to `echo $market->cities;` because you should be looping through it and also, that's not the name of your relationship.  Try `echo $market->citys()->count();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method looks correct. However, note that you have named it `citys` instead of `cities`, which may or may not have been a typo while posting your question here. The correct plural form of `city` is `cities` and you should correct it because Laravel often uses automatic pluralization and assumes you'll get your English right.

Also, your model is called `Market`, while in the comments you're calling `GTM_Market`.

It's also assumed that the `Market` object does not have a `cities` property, so it will successfully fall back to the method which then fires the relationship query. If you happen to declare the property beforehand, Laravel will never reach the method.

```
class Market extends Eloquent {

    public $cities = 'Foo';

    public function cities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('City');
    }
}

$market = Market::find(205);

echo $market->cities; // Echoes 'Foo' instead of the relationship.
```

Lastly, with all of the above taken care of, you'd be able to eager-load the relationship like so:

```
Market::with('cities')->find(205);
```

Comment: The name of the method can be anything. Laravel does not use the name of the method to determine the table name. Laravel uses the name of the model/class to determine the table name if the table name is not defined. That being said, it is proper to use `cities()` instead of `citys`.

Comment: @Jakobud I mentioned it more as a general rule, but the typo seemed significant because he stated in the comments he was actually calling `cities`, like this: `$market = GTM_Market::find(205); echo $market->cities`